# Where can I ask a question about companies that profit of protecting the environment

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I'm writing a documentation for school that involves people who turn a profit out of protecting the environment. I.e they don't do it for "charity" exclusively.

These companies/people are hard to find on google without knowing at least some info about them. Where would be the correct place for me to pose this question?

Comment: Such a question is probably not a good fit for the Stack Exchange system. Read [this blog article](https://stackoverflow.blog/2012/02/29/lets-play-the-guessing-game/) and see the [help center about the close reason too broad](/help/closed-questions). Be sure to read the [tour] and what's [on-topic](/help/on-topic) *on the target site* if you are shown a seemingly fitting site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, there is no SE site that is suitable for this question.

Check out [Area 51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/) to propose a new SE site once you have enough support for a proposal. This will probably never be fit for SE as it is [too broad.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions)

Comment: ... and there probably never will be a site suitable for this type of question. Read my comment on the question.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard yeah true, i'll add that